# Oracle BPM Fault Recovery By java API

Tags: java, api, recovery, business-process-management, fault

Any one have used java API to recover Oracle BPM fault?
I'm using the following code to recover BPM faults the code is running successfully but no changes have been made on the instance fault, even the fault modified date didn't change, unlike clicking retry button on the fault itself using the em.

```
package oracle.bpm.example;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import java.util.List;

import javax.naming.Context;

import oracle.soa.management.facade.Fault;
import oracle.soa.management.facade.FaultRecoveryActionTypeConstants;
import oracle.soa.management.facade.Locator;
import oracle.soa.management.facade.LocatorFactory;
import oracle.soa.management.facade.bpmn.BPMNServiceEngine;
import oracle.soa.management.util.FaultFilter;

/**
 * Note: the classes in oracle.soa.management.facade.bpmn and subpackages are
 * not part of the public API and are provided as part of an as-is example 
 * for use in solving data issues in the current release.  This example 
 * is provided only to illustrate an approach for batch recover of instances
 * and should be modified to meet environment specific requirments and 
 * thoroughly tested, including removal of userid and passwords.
 */
public class BatchFaultRecovery {


    public BatchFaultRecovery() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locator locator = getLocator("t3://mydev:7001/soa-infra", "username", "password");
        doRecovery(locator,"FaultHandlingExample", "Client", "ServiceTask");
    }
    
    public static void doRecovery(Locator locator, String compositeName, String componentName, String activityName) {
        try {
            BPMNServiceEngine svcEngine = (BPMNServiceEngine)locator.getServiceEngine(Locator.SE_BPMN);
            FaultFilter faultFilter = new FaultFilter();
            faultFilter.setCompositeName(compositeName);
            faultFilter.setComponentName(componentName);
            recoverFaults(svcEngine, faultFilter,activityName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }

    public static Locator getLocator(String url, String user, String password) {
        try {
            Hashtable jndiProps = new Hashtable();
            jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,url);
            jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
            jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
            jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            jndiProps.put("dedicated.connection", "true");
            return LocatorFactory.createLocator(jndiProps);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Error getting Locator",e);
        }
     }

    public static void recoverFaults(BPMNServiceEngine svcEngine, FaultFilter faultFilter, String activityName) {
        System.out.println("Get Recoverable Faults");
        try {
            faultFilter.setRecoverable(true);
            //Get faults using defined filter
            List<Fault> recoverableFaults = svcEngine.getFaults(faultFilter);
            for (Fault fault : recoverableFaults) {
           System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>");
           System.out.println("Composite         :"+fault.getCompositeDN().getCompositeName());
           System.out.println("Composite Instance:"+fault.getCompositeInstanceId());
           System.out.println("Component         :"+fault.getComponentName());
           System.out.println("Component Instance:"+fault.getComponentInstanceId());
           System.out.println("Reference         :"+fault.getReferenceName());
           System.out.println("Service           :"+fault.getServiceName());
           System.out.println("Label             :"+fault.getLabel());
           System.out.println("Fault Id          :"+fault.getId());
           System.out.println("Fault Name        :"+fault.getName());
           System.out.println("isRecoverable     :"+fault.isRecoverable());
           System.out.println("Message           :"+fault.getMessage());

            
           //Retry  fault
           System.out.println("Start recovery ...");
           svcEngine.recoverFault(fault,FaultRecoveryActionTypeConstants.ACTION_RETRY,null);
           System.out.println("Finish recovery");
           System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<");
     
         }
       } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
}
```

can any one help me to trace or find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This question is resolved using the following method, Its working fine and the instance recovered:

```
bpmnServiceEngine.recoverCallbackMessages(BPMCallbackMessage);
```

but i still need to know the deference between **bpmnServiceEngine.recoverCallbackMessages(BPMCallbackMessage)**
and **bpmnServiceEngine.recoverFault(Fault)** !!.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it in the docs :
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/soasuite/api-reference-soa/toc.htm

Check at the documentation of "bpmnServiceEngine" class. By [Ctrl + Click] on the same classname. And analize both methods or paste them here. Also please don't add exclamation signs, We are colaborating here not demanding. Best.